# Как упаковать .txt файл в exe с помощью PyInstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

В гугле куча подобных вопросов, но вот ответов - нет, к сожалению. Имеется Python скрипт, который хранит некие параметры в текстовом файле. То есть просто читает  его/записывает в него через `open("file.txt")`.
Подскажите новичку, есть ли простой способ упаковать его в exe pyinstaller'ом?

Comment: Если бы вы смогли это сделать, то не смогли бы записывать в него что-либо. Если это файл параметров/настроек, то он и не должен быть частью исполняемого файла, а должен находиться рядом с ним

Comment: Почему? PyInstaller собирает само распаковывающийся архив во время запуска этот file.txt будет распакован во временную папку вопрос в том как поместить его в архив

Answer (score 0):

При запуске утилиты **pyinstaller**, естественно с аргументами.

Генерируется файл с расширением **.spec**

Типа такого:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\PY_EXE\\Exsample'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)

a.datas += [('Имя> file.txt','Полный путь до файла> C:\\file.txt ','Тип> TXT')] #<--Внимание на эту строку её нужно добавить в этот spec файл 

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name='main',
      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=True )
```

И ещё один нюанс нужно в вашем файле **file.py**

Создать такую функцию:

```
def resource_path(relative):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative)
    else:
        return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative)

# Доступ к file.txt только так
with open(resource_path('file.txt'), 'r') as file:
    file.read()
    pass
```

Теперь заново соберите EXE-ник только теперь таким образом:

**pyinstaller file.spec**

*И радуйтесь)*